# Error creating window handle in an .NET MDI application

Tags: .net, tabs, window, mdi

I have an MDI application with tab controls. On some machines I get "Error creating window handle" exception when opening up a new tab. This is only occurs at some machines, mostly slow machines. 
.NET Framework 4.0 is used.

I have been investigating the issue for the last couple of days now and it has driven me nuts! I found the following on MSDN forums
The solution by Hans Passant at this [MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/e5d0721e-166a-426f-adff-ef00c2f541e0/)
And according to the answer it has something to do with the active MDI child being in maximized state. The given solution is to set the active child in normal window state before showing the new tab and then restore it afterwards. This solution works but I really dislike the flickering that the workaround causes.

The stack trace is as follows:

Error creating window handle:

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.WindowClass.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, 
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams cp)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.get_Handle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(Boolean value)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show()
   at Client.UI.WinForms.Controls.TabManager.OpenNewTab(BaseTab2 tab) in WinForms\Forms\Tabs\TabManager.cs:line 82
   at Client.UI.WinForms.Controls.TabManager.OpenTab(BaseTab2 tab) in WinForms\Forms\Tabs\TabManager.cs:line 183
   at Client.UI.WinForms.MainForm.buttonLicenses_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in WinForms\Forms\MainForm.cs:line 4372
```

Code:

```
    private void OpenNewTab(BaseTab2 tab)
    {
        tab.MdiParent = MainForm.Instance;
        tab.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        tab.Show(); <----- [EXCEPTION THROWN HERE]

        if (tab.Path != String.Empty)
        {
            RecentManager.Add(tab.Path);
            RecentManager.SetOpen(tab.Path, true);
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: Found this at [Microsoft support](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949458)
This can occur when both the following conditions are true.

1. The MDI child form contains a control which parents other controls.
2. The parent control on the MDI child form removes a child control from its Controls collection in the event handler for the Layout or Resize events.

Comment: So basically, you're looking for an *alternative* to the solution Hans proposes in the MSDN thread? One that avoids the flicker?

Comment: Can you avoid the flicker by calling SuspendLayout/ResumeLayout?

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft Support article is the same scenario as the MSDN forum post you found.  It isn't a good match with yours.  Diagnose this with Taskmgr.exe, Processes tab.  View + Select Columns and tick Handles, USER objects and GDI objects.  Observe these values for your process while you are using it.

The likely scenario is that you'll see the USER objects value climb without bound.  Windows pulls the rug out when it reaches 10000, that's way too many windows to be created by one process.

It is caused by removing controls from their parent in your code without calling their Dispose() method.  If the Taskmgr.exe doesn't help you find it then search your code for "Controls.Remove" or "Controls.Clear".  Maybe you're removing a tab page.  The control(s) you remove are temporarily re-parented to the 'parking window'.  They'll get stuck there forever if you don't give them another parent or don't call their Dispose() method.  That's a leak.  The code that bombs is not the code that caused the problem.

Comment: When the crash happens the User Objects is around 170, GDI Objects around 170 and Hadels is around 350.

If in your opinion the problem is caused because we are reaching the max limit supported by .net or windows then can you please explain why does this happen on only some computers?. 

It happens on computers have low memory/processing power.
thanks

Comment: Well, scratch that then.  You can't get rid of the repaints.  If you constantly maximize an MDI child then MDI isn't the right windowing model.  Use a simple form that displays and disposes one of several user controls.

Comment: The solution/workaround you proposed on MSDN forums works, so the Handles cannot be the problem I guess. 

The workaround is good, except for the "flickering". Maybe flickering is not the correct word to use. Whats happening is that the MDI child goes from maximized state to normal state and the again back to maximized state - and this procedure does not look nice at all. This is what I refer as "flickering"

Comment: Erm, why does it go back to maximized?  If you don't want the new child to be maximized then just delete the last statement from the workaround code in the MSDN forums post.

Comment: I want the new child to be maximized. That's why :-)

Comment: MDI already goes through the restore + switch + maximize cycle, even without you helping it to do it early so the bug won't byte.  Yes, the amount of repainting (3 times) is quite noticeable if the child forms have a lot of controls.  The only fix for that is to use less controls.